# JQuery .toggle('Slide') is not displaying my content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a Social Media links for a website, but what supposed to happen is once a user hovers over the Icon is slides out on the right hand side of the Social Media/Link icon.
I have this JQuery code that controls what happens on a users hover:

```
$("#share").hover(function() {
      $("#social-icon-content").toggle('slide');
      $("#share a").animate({opacity:'1'}, 1);
      $("#share-button").animate({opacity:'1'}, 1);
    });
```

When looking in the console of Google chrome it shows that is is sliding the content but after it finishes sliding nothing happens and it switches from `display: none;` to `display: block;`.

Here is a link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/he7cq201/#&togetherjs=zTodlRlAJ8) if you'd like to see more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do:

1. add `float: left` property for `#share-button` and `#social-icon-content`
2. set `width: 230px; display: block;` for `.wsite-social.wsite-social-default`
3. set `position: absolute` property for `#social-icon-content`
4. add `display: inline-block; float: left;` property for `.wsite-social-item`

That's it!

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z24qfcj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is displayed since nothing is put in the links.

```
<a href="link">Text To be shown</a>
```

You haven't entered any text b/w link tags.

If you want to display the background image without any text there are two options :

1. Add height & width to the span & make display block.

   span{
   display:block;
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
   }
2. Add padding to the span which has background image.

   span{
   padding:20px;
   }

A working example with few changes in your code : [Working](https://jsfiddle.net/ani1/d3ykyr9f/3/)

Comment: The CSS has images/backgrounds

Comment: There isnt supposed to be text

Comment: @Tarson if you want to display images without text, just set the width & height for the spans which contain the images.

Comment: @Tarson If you don't want to set height & with to span, just give it padding.
`padding:20px;`

Comment: @AniMenon Clicking on your "Working" JSFiddle seems to link to the original fiddle with out your fix.

Comment: .wsite-social-icon{display:block;} it helped in there the icons are now displaying but they are horizontal now i need it to be vertical!

Comment: Now the link works.
To get it all vertically use `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @Tarson I hope your query is answered.

Comment: @AniMenon It helped us get the answer!